# Keeping test and development databases in sync with rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using Rails 4.2, I want to add an age field to my `User` ActiveRecord class in a Postgres database using this line in a migration:

```
add_column :users, :age, :integer
```

then I obviously ran `bin/rake db:migrate`. Later I decided to make this a `string` field so rolled the migration back and changed the migration like so:

```
add_column :users, :age, :string
```

and migrated again. All was fine in my development database, but my test database seemed to have retained the old datatype. This is what I got using `psql` and running `select column_name, data_type from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'users';`

In development:

```
age          | character varying
```

In test:

```
age          | integer
```

Is this intentional or a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha! The issue is that the ActiveRecord feature below does not support rolling back of migrations:

```
ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!
```

and is detailed in this issue https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/15787, it seems this will be fixed in Rails 5.

Answer (score 4):

First it's seldom a good idea to change a migration after it has already been applied.

But since you're already there, there are two possible ways to go about this: either rollback and migrate the test database or just load the schema for the test database. I recommend the second solution: just `RAILS_ENV=test rake db:schema:load` and you're good to go.

Comment: Yeah that is what I did (second recommendation), but it seems strange to me that if you are going to support migrating both databases that you don't support rolling them both back correctly. I think I am going to open a support query with Rails.

Comment: You can of course `RAILS_ENV=test rake db:rollback db:migrate`. But it would be unexpected behaviour to implicitly roll back `test` while in another environment.

Comment: OK, but `rake db:migrate` implicitly created the column in the test environment database. Would it not be expected that it implicitly rolls it back as well?

Answer (score 0):

When you run a db:migrate, if you don't specify environment, it'll only run the migrations for your development database. If you do a db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test, it'll run the migrations against your test database.